# Unable to load image asset

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble debugging my project on flutter. I want to load image assets in my project but even though my code has the correct indentation with no errors I'm still unable to load the image asset.

Code for adding asset in pubsec.yaml:
[image]

Code for using the assing the asset:
[image]

Comment: Try to 1) escape the backslashs (i.e. replacing '\' with '\\') or 2) use a forward slash (/) instead of a backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much guys! The error was the foward slashes
I'll give you the screenshots if someone needs help

https://gyazo.com/757af72d4873ace846f72cae472531b9
and here is the pubspec.yaml file

https://gyazo.com/48e081d9bc0091aaed013d079cc847ce

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you are doing things correctly I'm providing an example format below for loading and using image assets.

- Check if the asset folder structure in your project is like this:

[image]

- Next load the asset in pubspec.yaml like this:

```
  assets:
    - assets/images/pdf.png
```

- After adding them do `pub get` and then completely restart the app.
- Now use the image asset in a project like this:

```
Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
            'assets/images/pdf.png',
             fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
             height: 150,
        ),
    ],
),
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! The error was the foward slashes