# unable load image asset in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not sure why my images from assets is not working

I looked at these two questions:

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64158543/flutter-unable-to-load-image-asset

-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67552389/unable-to-load-image-asset

this is how I am trying to fetch the image:

```
          Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
          ),
```

here is my pubspec.yaml

```
 assets:
    - assets/logo.png
    - assets/back.png
```

below is the file structure
[image: this is the file structure]

I tried following videos on youtube but that didnt work.

any suggestions are welcome

Comment: what error are you receiving?

Comment: your code is perfect. Just stop running your app and start it again. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

if your images are in images folder of assets folder then declare as below in pubspec.yaml

```
assets:
  - assets/images/
```

And write code to get image as below

```
Image(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and change your `pubspec.yaml` file like-

if your images in images folder

```
 assets:
    - assets/images
```

if your images in assetsfolder

```
 assets:
    - assets/
```

after that run command `flutter pub get` and Stop the code and **re-run** again

Refer [assets-and-images](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up restarting the app then everyting worked